# ActiveMQ Artemis JDBC Store: Add connection pool for DB connections?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I use the latest version of ActiveMQ Artemis with the MySQL database as message store. After 8h my server times out client db connections. The [AbstractJDBCDriver](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-jdbc-store/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jdbc/store/drivers/AbstractJDBCDriver.java) implementation in Artemis does not recognize this and throws an exception.

What to do? I see no possibility for a DB connection pool with this implementation.

```
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) [mysql-connector-java.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) [mysql-connector-java.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2056) [mysql-connector-java.jar:8.0.19]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver.stop(AbstractJDBCDriver.java:108) [artemis-jdbc-store-2.10.0.redhat-00004.jar:2.10.0.redhat-00004]
```

Same question [here](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Artemis-does-not-reconnect-to-MySQL-after-connection-timeout-tt4751956.html#none).

Answer (score 0):

At this point the best thing to do is to restart the broker when this happens. There currently is no DB connection pool implementation, as you note.

Comment: Hmmm :(

Last try was to analyze the code. In general, the code is prepared to accept a pooled DataSurce (e.g. c3p0). But the setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) in this class https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/config/storage/DatabaseStorageConfiguration.java is only used in tests and cannot be set in the broker-xml configuration.

Comment: Like this, the configuration parser always uses the jdbc driver directly.
https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/31e71ba90521d0ad6306fd56864cb27de87c366d/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/deployers/impl/FileConfigurationParser.java (createDatabaseStoreConfig)

Comment: The code could certainly be modified to use a pool, but the pool will only help if it implements some kind of connection checking mechanism before handing out a connection.

Comment: Exactly! This is  what https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int) is used for. My current solution: Send ping messages to the broker to keep db connections alive (hmpf..)

Comment: Useless. I tried to frequently poll the database via amq7-broker/bin/artemis address show but there are still other db connections timing out. Using a message store with Artemis is definitely experimental. Don't use it in production.

Comment: That's clearly noted in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/persistence.html#jdbc-persistence) which says, "WARNING: The Apache ActiveMQ Artemis JDBC persistence store is under development and is included for evaluation purposes."

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Artemis release (2.16.0) there is support for connection-pooling.

Basic example with MySQL:

0. Create a new broker instance:

```sh
$ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis create hosts/host0 --name host0 --user admin --password admin --require-login
```

1. Start the database and create a dedicated instance:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE activemq CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
CREATE USER 'activemq'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'activemq';
GRANT CREATE,SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,INDEX ON activemq.* TO 'activemq'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2. Download and copy the specific JDBC driver:

```sh
curl -sL https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.tar.gz -o driver.tar.gz
tar xf driver.tar.gz && cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.22/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar hosts/host0/lib/
```

3. Add JDBC storage with connection-pooling configuration:

```xml
<store>
    <database-store>
        <data-source-properties>
            <!-- All configuration options: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html -->
            <data-source-property key="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <data-source-property key="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activemq" />
            <data-source-property key="username" value="activemq" />
            <data-source-property key="password" value="activemq" />
            <data-source-property key="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
            <!-- Avoid MySQL default behavior of killing long lived connections after 1 hour -->
            <data-source-property key="maxConnLifetimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        </data-source-properties>
        <bindings-table-name>BINDINGS</bindings-table-name>
        <message-table-name>MESSAGES</message-table-name>
        <large-message-table-name>LARGE_MESSAGES</large-message-table-name>
        <page-store-table-name>PAGE_STORE</page-store-table-name>
        <node-manager-store-table-name>NODE_MANAGER_STORE</node-manager-store-table-name>
    </database-store>
</store>
```